# Kubernetes persistent volume claim - "Cannot bind to requested volume "": storageClassName does not match

Tags: kubernetes, persistent-volumes

I'm currently trying to create a Persistent Volume Claim but is throwing the error:
"Cannot bind to requested volume "pv": storageClassName does not match"

```
resource "google_compute_disk" "default" {
  name = "pv"
  type = "pd-ssd"
  zone = "us-east1-a"
  size = 2
}

resource "kubernetes_persistent_volume" "default" {
  metadata {
   name = "pv"
  }
  spec {
    capacity = {
     storage = "2Gi"
   }
 access_modes = ["ReadWriteMany"]
 persistent_volume_source {
  gce_persistent_disk {
    pd_name = "pv"
    fs_type = "ext4"
    }
  }
 }
}

resource "kubernetes_persistent_volume_claim" "default" {
 metadata {
  name = "pv"
 }
 spec {
  access_modes = ["ReadWriteMany"]
  resources {
    requests = {
      storage = "2Gi"
    }
  }
  storage_class_name = "pv"
  volume_name        = "pv"
  }
 }
```

I've tried to follow [Why does a match Persistent Volume not bind to a match Persistent Volume Claim (using k3s)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66042100/why-does-a-match-persistent-volume-not-bind-to-a-match-persistent-volume-claim), however I still get the same issue of "Cannot bind to requested volume "pv": storageClassName does not match"

How can I fix this issue?  - I've tried to ensure that the name of all the resources match, but I think I'm missing something.

Any help on this will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What is the syntax you're using here? In any case, in your PVC you're setting `storage_class_name = "pv"`. What is the storage class name of the PV itself? (E.g., if you `kubectl get pv pv -o yaml`; you're looking for the `storageClassName` attribute).

Comment: Hi - I ran the command, and it does not have a `storageClassName` attribute. There is a `name` under `metadata` and that is `pv`

Comment: What happens if you remove the `storage_class_name` setting from your PVC?

Comment: So I updated the kubernetes_persistent_volume to also have `storage_class_name = "pv"`. This seems to set the persistent volume to Bound and get past the error. However, the pod never starts up due to `6 persistentvolumeclaim "pv" not found` so I'm not sure if this is the correct solution.

Comment: Well, it's the opposite of what I suggested (and to be fair, I don't know if my suggestion will work, either), but perhaps it's worth a try.

Comment: Thanks @larsks I removed `storage_class_name ` from PVC and I get the error: `storageClassName does not match` same as in the original question.

Comment: Hi fuzzi, can you provide what k8s version and cluster platform/infrastructure are you using?

Comment: @PiotrMalec GKE, version 1.21.6-gke.1500

Answer (score 0):

You might change

```
storage_class_name = "pv"
```

to

```
storage_class_name = "manual"
```